# See per-app cache-misses?

Tags: resource-monitoring

This is what I mean by cache miss:

> If the processor finds that the memory location is in the cache, a cache hit has occurred. However, if the processor does not find the memory location in the cache, a cache miss has occurred.

I want to see why my apps take 5-6 seconds to switch to after my phone has been idle with its screen locked, and no WiFi or mobile data. Some program running in the background must have generated a ton of cache misses and filled up the entire L2 cache with its own data.

Is there a way to see, per-app, how many cache misses are being generated?